# Why does IntelliSense show a constructor I didn't write?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, intellisense

What does it mean by the suggestion give by the IDE? (using VS 2010)

[image]

There is no constructor of baseClass_2 which takes the suggested parameter(**const baseClass_2 &**). So, why this is showing up?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Implicitly defined copy constructor.

There are special member functions which get defined by default when you not explicitly declare / define them:

- Default constructor
- Copy constructor
- Destructor

Note that the default constructor will not get defined when you provide *any* other constructor besides the copy constructor.

Answer (score 4):

The constructor is the copy constructor and it is declared and defined implicitly.